# string concatination at specificv value

Tags: python

these items are in a list
    SF-04-08-010-MD01,
    AHU-VVIP-02-003-MD03,
    AHU-02-17-019-DPS03,
    AHU-T3-01-PL-TS01,
    EF-03-32-108-MD01,
    AHU-02-16-019-MD01,
    AHU-T3-01-003-MD01,
    SF-04-08-010-MD01,
    AHU-VVIP-02-003-MD03,

so i want a new list which should be like

```
SF-04-08
AHU-VVIP
AHU-02-17
AHU-T3-01
EF-03-32
AHU-02-16
AHU-T3-01
SF-04-08
AHU-VVIP-02
```

using python??

Comment: Try editing your question and properly format code snippets, as it's pretty unreadable at this point. Also, `AHU-VVIP` in the desired output doesn't match the (textual) requirements.

Comment: What's the rule? First "-" after *n* characters? *n* "blocks" from the end?

Answer (score 1):

you can use strip like:

```
data = ['SF-04-08-010-MD01',
'AHU-VVIP-02-003-MD03',
'AHU-02-17-019-DPS03'
]

for item in data:
    print ('-'.join(item.split('-')[:3]))
```

output:

```
SF-04-08
AHU-VVIP-02
AHU-02-17
```